# whats wrong with my code, im using photon pun 2 in unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, photon

so im trying to make a vr game in unity and im following a tutorial for how to make a multiplayer game and imported the photon pun 2 and copied this code but when i try to build or start the ggame i get there [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qKvq.jpg)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class networkmanager : MonoBehaviourPunCallBacks
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ConnectToServer();
    }

    void ConnectToServer()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
        Debug.Log("Conecting To Server...");
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected To Server!");
        base.OnConnectedToMaster();
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 10;
        roomOptions.IsVisible = true;
        roomOptions.IsOpen = true;

        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("Lobby 1", roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("Lobby Joined!");
        base.OnJoinedRoom();
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("A New Player Has Joined The Lobby!");
        base.OnPlayerEnteredRoom(newPlayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: replace MonoBehaviourPunCallBacks with MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks and those errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

You uppercased b in backs in MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks. It must be lowercase